# Logback doesn't print any log in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, logback, weblogic12c

I want to move to `Logback` from `java.util.logging.Logger`. First I use this in  my `dependency.jar` file. `MyApp.ear` is still use `java logger`.

Below is `logback.xml`.

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
     ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n  
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="WARN">          
     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

I added below depended jar files to my `ant build` file.

```
  <pathelement location="${global.lib}/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${global.lib}/logback-classic-1.0.1.jar"/>
```

I use `weblogic 12C`. Now my log level is `WARN`. But still the `INFO` logs are printing. Which means it still uses `java logger`. I suspect the `dependent.jar` `logback` `log` is overwritten by `java logger` in `MyApp.ear`.

I am not sure is there any place to modify in the `weblogic 12C`to enable it.

`logback.xml` is available inside the `dependency.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My problem resolved. Now working fine. BTW I have missed `logback-core-1.0.10.jar` in the `build.xml`

Comment: If you want, you can post your solution of adding the jar file to your build.xml as an answer so that people know the problem is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added below jar path to my `build.xml`

```
<pathelement location="${global.lib}/logback/logback-core-1.0.10.jar"/>
```

Additionally I added below code to my `weblogic-application.xml`.

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:prefer-application-resources>
    <wls:resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</wls:resource-name>
</wls:prefer-application-resources>
```

This resolved my issue.