# logback logs are not printing on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, logback, weblogic12c

I know this question has been asked on URL : [Logback doesn't print any log in Weblogic 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883375/logback-doesnt-print-any-log-in-weblogic-12c) , But even after putting below lines in weblogic-application.xml .

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>ch.qos.logback.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.lang.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.apache.logging.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</wls:package-name> 
    <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>  
<wls:prefer-application-resources>
    <wls:resource-name>org/slf4j/Logger.class</wls:resource-name>
    <wls:resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</wls:resource-name>
    <wls:resource-name>org/apache/log4j/Level/Logger.class</wls:resource-name>
</wls:prefer-application-resources>
```

my application is still not printing logs. logback-core,logback-classic,sl4j jars are available in EAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in my system is that due to prefer-application-packages in weblogic-application.xml server is looking for that package into my EAR. My EAR have both logback-core and logback-classic jars.So ideally logabck logs should work but same package(org.sl4j.*) is also available in  activemq-all-5.8.0.jar with log4j implementation, which is in my EAR too . So it did not let my logback logs work .